# Can't center images in column

Tags: magento2, css, media-images

Magento 2 (2.1.10). I can't get my images to center within this block.

I have three columns. I want the left column to have centered text and images.

```
<style>
.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
.middle, .right {
  width: 25%;
}
.left {
  width: 50%;
}
.text-center {
   text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
} 
</style>
```

Images I can't seem to center (h2/normal text center, including link at end of images):

```
<div class="column left text-center">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    Summary.<br /> <br /> 
    <div class="lazyload" data-ui="jscroll-images">
        <img class="lazy" data-original="/image1.jpg" width="300" height="382" />
        <img style="padding-top: 5px;" class="lazy" data-original="/image2.jpg" width="300" height="374" /> 
        <img style="padding-top: 5px;" class="lazy" data-original="/image3.jpg" width="300" height="382" />
        <img style="padding-top: 5px;" class="lazy" data-original="/image4.jpg" width="300" height="374" />
    <p style="clear: both;"><br><br><a href="">See more!</a></p>
</div>
```

I had to add the `p style` because otherwise the See more! link ended up next to image1.

I have also tried adding the following css, which changed nothing:

```
img {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

And tried adding the margins to .left:

```
.left {
      width: 50%;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
    }
```

When I remove `float: left;` from `.column`, then my middle/right columns end up below the left column.

I wish `<center>` tags would work :'(

Comment: image {display: inline-block}

Comment: try this 
.lazy {
 float: left;
 width: 32%;
 padding: 8px;
}

Comment: I should've mentioned I tried `image {display: inline-block}` - tried again just now to be sure; does not fix. 
Tried the `.lazy` css. Didn't center and stopped the lazyload from functioning.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the float:left; was at odds with the margin:auto;. I needed the float:left; for other formatting, so I simply added to the image style tags "padding-top: 5px; float:none !important;" and that fixed it!